# Custom module select specific entries from database via resource model?

Tags: magento2

I have set my resource model up, my model for it and I have pulled Item 1 from the database...

How do I select rows from the database that have a 'quote_id' of say 9?

```
 public function getQuoteProducts()
 {
   $quoteDataModel = $this->_quoteDataModelFactory->create();
    $item = $quoteDataModel->load(1);
    var_dump($item->getData());
    ...And so on.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just pass in the quote ID you wish to load, so you could change your function to something like this.

```
public function getQuoteProducts($quoteid)
 {
   $quoteDataModel = $this->_quoteDataModelFactory->create();
    $item = $quoteDataModel->load($quoteid);
    var_dump($item->getData());
    return $this->_quote->getQuoteProducts();
 }
```

and then call your function

```
$this->getQuoteProducts(9);
```

Comment: Ah, so that ->load function that I did not define is working according to the table entry primary???

What if I want to load by a different field?

Comment: It depends on the field really, i know in magento1 there is a loadByCustomer() function where you can pass in a customer, i should imagine this exists in magento2 aswell.

Comment: ->load($value, $fieldname) works for me, but it will only load one, and if the value isn't unique it won't warn you there are more.